# ECMA 6 syntax for Promise()

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

How can I modify this promise code to throw an error if the response contains some error code in the response body?

```
return this.httpService.post('/create', data)
                       .toPromise()
                       .then(response => response.json() as CreatedResponse)
                       .catch(this.handleCreateError);
```

It's the `.then(response => response.json() as CreatedResponse)` I need to modify to throw an error if `response.json().hasError` is true. Otherwise the promise should just resolve.

Comment: Add `.then(json => json.hasError ? Promise.reject() : json)`

Comment: @4castle I was about to post something like you commented.

Answer (score 3):

You can throw any errors in your `then` callback. so in your case it could be:

```
return this.httpService.post('/create', data)
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(response => response.json() as CreatedResponse)
                   .then(json => {
                       if (json.hasError) {
                           throw Error('Response is not valid');
                       } else {
                           return json;
                       }
                   })
                   .catch(this.handleCreateError);
```